# Difficulty in finding differential gene expression from FireBrowse TCGA data

Tags: r

I am working on LUAD data from FireBrowse and using RNASeqV2 RSEM normalized data of gene expression. I want to find out the DEG between Tumor samples of stage I and stage IV. But I'm not able to get any DEG between stage I and stage IV, but I hope that is not the case that there will be no DEG between those two stages of tumor samples.
I tried to find DEG between stage I and II or stage I and stage III and so on making groups within the stages but still no luck.

I have asked a question regarding this topic in Bioconductor support group where I have posted my complete R code to find the DEG between Stage I and IV, [link to my question at bioconductor](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/107621/))

My questions are,
1) What preprocessing is to be done for such RNAseq V2 RSEM data to use it for differential gene expression analysis?

2) how to extract samples on stage I and stage IV from the gene expression data?

I look forward to hearing all of your suggestions and answers.
Your suggestions would make me understand where I'm going wrong in this analysis.

Comment: Check topTable without setting the limit for p.value and lfc. I am sure that you have no significant genes on p.value = 0.05 and lfc = 2. You can also check by increasing the limit of p.value.

Comment: Thank you so much for the your attention, I tried to use topTable without p.value and lfc, but it's gives all genes and the that number is more than 17000. And I have not tried by increasing the limit of p.value that I will surely try but my I'm interested in genes with p value less than 0.05 that is why I chose that.

Comment: Well, there is no gene with the p-value less than 0.05 and lfc = 2, so you can try by reducing the limit of lfc e.g, lfc = .5 or so.

Comment: Hi Aaghaz Hussain,  I check for lfc = 0.5 but still no change

Comment: It simply means that the samples you are comparing do not show any differential expression. Please check the groups you are comparing properly. Make sure that you are using two different groups. After all, if you don't get any differentially expressed gene on a certain threshold, it means there is none.

Comment: And according to [this post](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/107621/) your problem is already solved as you have accepted the answer

Comment: I accepted as there were some mistakes with my code but my problem is not solved yet. if you know something that i'm missing out please tell me. according to your comment that, no genes at certain threshold  then how to make sure that, the workflow i'm using is not wrong?